# Error Number: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql

I was testing my software which is in cpanel. But I am getting this whenever I run a single page. Other pages are working properly. the database table is having 12000+ data.is it because it takes much time to load

The same works perfect in localhost. Just now I uploaded it to cpanel.

### Query

```
SELECT * FROM `service_sales_invoice` LEFT JOIN `service_sales_invoice_data` ON `service_sales_invoice`.`invoice_number` = `service_sales_invoice_data`.`invoice_number` WHERE `date` >= '2019-05-01' AND `date` <= '2019-06-20' ORDER BY `date`
```

Expected result is it works properly. But not.

Comment: i would suggest into reading how you should write valid [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) queries.  As the general rule is *"SQL-92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause. "*

Comment: Ok, I will read on that. But can you help me with this issue now?

Comment: *"But can you help me with this issue now? "* No see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as SQL is a declarative lauguage..

Comment: @RaymondNijland. I know, I'm sorry.  But please help me with this if you know the issue. I need to submit this project for testing. I can submit this only if this issue gets over.

Comment: please tell me your MySQL version